# Get first Tuesday of month every year

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I want to use sql or python to get the first Tuesday in June for the current year.

For example:

- The year is 2020, so I need to return 06/02/2020
- The year is 2021, so I need to return 06/01/2021

Comment: SQL is a language bur we also need info for which database do you need the solution for. Also, it would be nice to see what have you tried? What was your effort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the python way.

```py
import datetime
def get_day(year):
    d = datetime.datetime(year, 6, 1)
    offset = 1-d.weekday() #weekday = 1 means tuesday
    if offset < 0:
        offset+=7
    return d+datetime.timedelta(offset)
```

Pass in the year to the function, it returns the first tuesday as a `datetime` object.

Comment: This works perfectly. To get the current year without hard coding a value I added this: ```current_year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)```. Then pasted ```current_year``` to the function. Then converted to string so that it can be concatenated in a string like this: ```fixByDate = fixByDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")```. I hope this can help someone else!

Comment: You can as well change `d = datetime.datetime.now()` and not accept an argument for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a very simple python function to get the day of the first tuesday given an year an a month.

```
import datetime as dt

def first_tuesday_of_month(year, month):
  d = dt.datetime(year, month, 1)
  wd = d.weekday()
  # monday
  if wd == 0:
    return 2
  # tuesday
  if wd == 1:
    return 1
  # wensday
  if wd == 2:
    return 7
  # thursday
  if wd == 3:
    return 6
  # friday
  if wd == 4:
    return 5
  # saturday
  if wd == 5:
    return 4
  # sunday 6
  if wd == 6:
    return 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(first_tuesday_of_month(2020, 6))
    print(first_tuesday_of_month(2020, 1))
    print(first_tuesday_of_month(2020, 2))
    print(first_tuesday_of_month(2021, 6))
```

Output

```
D:\workspace\stackoverflow\python>python first_tuesday_of_month.py
2
7
4
1
```